# Почему на паскале АВС на if программа дает ошибку.(Program8.pas(9) : Встречено 'if', а ожидалось ';')

Tags: pascal

```
Function F(x:integer):integer;
begin
  F:= 2*x*x + 8*x + 10;
end;

BEGIN
  Readln(a,b);
  M:=а; 
  R:=F(а);
  for t:=a to b do bеgin
    if (F(t)>R) thеn bеgin
      М:=t;
      R:=F(t);
      writеln(M,f(t));
    end;
  end;
  writeln(M,f(t));
end;
write(M);
END
```

сообщение компилятора:

> [pabcnetc.exe]Старт компиляции сборки Program8.pas...
>
> [pabcnetc.exe]Начало компиляции Program8.pas... 1 ошибок Встречено 'if', а ожидалось ';'
>
> [pabcnetc.exe]Компиляция завершена Program8.pas
>
> [pabcnetc.exe]Готов

Comment: сообщение компилятора     [pabcnetc.exe]Старт компиляции сборки Program8.pas...
[pabcnetc.exe]Начало компиляции Program8.pas...
1 ошибок
Встречено 'if', а ожидалось ';'
[pabcnetc.exe]Компиляция завершена Program8.pas
[pabcnetc.exe]Готов

Comment: это надо добавлять в текст вопроса, а не комментарием

Comment: и мне кажется у вас количество begin меньше количества end

Comment: сейчас посмотрю

Comment: все равно не отстаёт от if

Answer (score 4):

Потому, что у вас часть букв - в латинском регистре, а часть - в русском, в частности, буквы е, М, а. И лишний end, как было верно замечено. Вот так будет правильно:

```
Function F(x:integer):integer;
begin
   F:= 2*x*x + 8*x + 10;
end;

var
  a, b, m, r ,t :  Integer;


BEGIN
   Readln(a,b);
   M:=a; R:=F(a);
   for t:=a to b do
      begin
        if (F(t) > R) then
           begin
              M:=t;
              R:=F(t);
              writeln(M,f(t));
           end;
      end;
   writeln(M,f(t));
   write(M);
END.
```

И старайтесь хоть как-то в будущем прилично форматировать код. Ведь его читать невозможно :)

Comment: Спасибо, просто я не знала как его сюда вбить. А так у меня такой же красивый как у вас. Ещё раз спасибо!